# Auto save mailing editing template in Mosaico

Tags: civimail, mosaico

I have a question about creating a mailing with mosaico (civicrm/a/#/mailing/[number]), Why does auto-save not always apply when is changed?

When you click close or test buttons its saved, but it doesn't do it automatically, although it does do it when accessing the template during the first two changes...

Has it always worked like this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Changes to the mailing are saved automatically (groups, subject, etc), but changes to the content (i.e. changes that you make in Mosaico) aren't saved automatically. So anything you change while in the Mosaico editor (with the Mosaico logo in the top left) isn't saved. It has always been this way.

It would be great if there was an autosave feature.

Comment: Thank you for your response

Comment: If you or anyone else wants to throw in some cash to try to get autosave added, we would be very willing to contribute some money. I'm sure it wouldn't be a huge project to implement this, but we'd have to check with the folks who maintain CiviCRM Mosaico to see what the cost might be.

Comment: Looking for a few good orgs who can chip in to help cover the cost of this.

Answer (score 2):

We have created an extension which bundles quite a few tools for handling mailings - it is called "[Mailingtools](https://github.com/systopia/de.systopia.mailingtools)".
The good news is that it has a feature which will warn you when you accidentally navigate away from the mosaico editing screen. You could use only that feature if you like.

1. Install the latest version of the extension
2. Navigate to /civicrm/admin/setting/mailingtools?reset=1
3. Check the box at the bottom "JS Warning to save Mosaico templates"

Comment: Thank you very much, it's been very useful.

Answer (score 0):

We potentially have a client interested in cosponsoring that feature - when you have info about possible cost - please post it here.

Comment: Have posted on Mosaico Gitlab about this, might be helpful to speak up there in support.
https://github.com/veda-consulting-company/uk.co.vedaconsulting.mosaico/issues/444

Comment: The cost to do this is not unreasonable (hundreds). We're looking for a few orgs to kick in smallish amounts and we can just get this done.

Comment: I'll ask my client if they are still interested. Can you give me a better idea about the cost? more like 300 or 900? :)

Comment: More like $900. We can also do a Make it Happen if that makes more sense.